# Freezing a cube on x ax, and make the freeze disappear

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a high cube that keep falling. I have freezed the X axis rotation on it. But when i do so, it looks weird when i collid with another cube. So i would like a script to stop the freeze on the X ax rotation when it collid with the second cube. If you have any idea please drop a comment.

Comment: *"i would like a script to"*.....

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please take some time to review the [tour] and [ask]. Try also to include a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you Like to un-freeze the X-Axis of your Rigidbody on Collision you can simply add a script to the Cube that contains something like:

```
void OnCollisionEnter(){
transform.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().freezeRotation = false;
}
```

make sure that both Cubes have a Rigidbody attached to them.

I don't know if unfreezing the Rigidbody's Rotationconstraints will fix your issue - if not there is multiple Ways to detect if the Cube will collide soon.

1. Raycasts

   ```
               var hit : RaycastHit;
               var dist : float;
               var dir : Vector3;

               function Update(){
                   dist = 2;
                   dir = Vector3(0, -1, 0);
                   Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, dir * dist, Color.green);
                   if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, dir, hit, dist))
                   {    
                       transform.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().freezeRotation = false;
                       //the ray collided with something, you can interact
                       // with the hit object now by using hit.collider.gameObject
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       //nothing was below your gameObject within 2m.
                   }
               }
   ```
2. A trigger Collider added to the Bottom of your Box.

[TriggerImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RmvLt.png)

Add the Code in the

```
void OnTriggerEnter(){

}
```

Funciton instead.